# Treat variables as symbols in Scheme

Tags: list, variables, scheme, racket, symbols

I have the following list

```
'(hash a (num 1 2) b (num 3 2) c (num 3 2) d (num 7 2))
```

in Scheme. I want to treat it as an expression by putting `eval` in front of it. But when I do that it gives me the error:
"Cannot reference an identifier before its definition".
My guess is it treats `a`, `b`, and `c` as if they were variables. But I want to treat them as symbols. Is this possible?

Comment: You need another quote on those symbols to suspend their evaluation. (On the other hand, when you want to `eval`, you're usually barking up the wrong tree, and rethinking the solution is a better idea than trying to fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you quote them of course:

```
'(hash 'a (num 1 2) 'b (num 3 2) 'c (num 3 2) 'd (num 7 2))
```

`eval` should be avoided, especially for user input, and I'm guessing there are a lot of ways you can make a hash without using eval if you knew the data:

```
; makes an alist
(define content `(a ,(num 1 2)
                  b ,(num 3 2)
                  c ,(num 3 2)
                  d ,(num 7 2)))

;; makes a hash
(define my-hash (apply hash content))
```

If this is really user input I would have paired it:

```
(define user-input '((a 1 2) (b 3 2) (d 7 2)))
(define content 
  ;; or use flatmap
  (apply append 
        (map (lambda (v) (list (car v) (num (cadr v) (caddr v)))) 
             user-input))) 

;; makes a hash
(define my-hash (apply hash content))
```